# Fast pure Python implementation of k-means

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm looking to do k-means clustering on an Google App Engine app (built for Google Glass).  The App Engine only accepts pure Python libraries.

I have tried using SciPy's `kmeans` and `kmeans2` edited to use `py_vq` instead of the C implementation of `vq`, but they take too long (~100 seconds) on ~500,000 x,y,z points and I get a `DeadlineExceededError` in my App Engine Logs.

I have already reduced my sample size by 90% to save on the memory limit, so I would like to shy away from reducing my sample size any more.

Are there any pure Python k-means libraries that are fast enough for Google App Engine?

Comment: Have you considered: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.vq.html ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, SciPy was what I was referring to with `kmeans` and `kmeans2` I'll add that to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a DeadlineExceededError, consider using a backend. Backends have no deadline and a configurable memory limit (not very high though, 1GB max).

See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know this was an option

Answer (score 0):

Well, the C implementation will certainly be faster than a pure python implementation...
For numerical stuff, pure python can be really expensive and slow. That is why the python libraries such as numpy and scipy have a lot of stuff implemented in faster languages in the backend.

You can also try to limit the number of iterations. The k-means result after 10 iterations will likely be as good as the final result in practise. It's the first iterations where things change a lot.